# Emmet for React.js Classes: "styles.something"

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-code, emmet

I am a React developer using VSCode. When you type `.hello`, it inserts`<div className="hello"></div>`. However, that is useless because my classes are `styles.something`, and I import `styles` from a stylesheet. How can I make Emmet insert `<div classsName={styles.hello}></div>` when typing `.hello`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type `.{styles.hello}`.

Then you get `<div className={styles.hello}></div>`